# Null Pointer during orientation change on DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, screen-orientation, navigation-drawer

I have this weird scenario wherein after the `onOrientationChange` I got a Null Pointer Error, my  DrawerLayout that has been initialized on `onCreateView` before the change.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

And I am getting null on this point,

```
 if(mDrawerList.getChildAt(position)!=null){
 }


private void selectItem(int position, boolean InstanceStateNull) {
         Log.d("selectItem", "inside");

        //savePosition("position", position);
           // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECT ITEM: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("SELECT ITEM: Position: ", ""+ position);

        this.mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        this.mDrawerList.setSelection(position);

        String selectedPid = null;
        //use mDrawerList.getChildAt(position) for not having null pointer
         if(mDrawerList.getChildAt(position)!=null)
         {
             //Extracts the string 
            TextView pid = (TextView)mDrawerList.getChildAt(position).findViewWithTag("pid");
            selectedPid =  pid.getText().toString(); 
            Log.d("SELECT ITEM: SELECTED ITEM: ", ""+ selectedPid.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED ITEM: "+ selectedPid
                     , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //saveSelecteditem("selectedItem", selectedPid);

         }
         else{
             Log.i("DrawerList on Orientation Change: ", "Null");
             //Log.i("DrawerList on Orientation Change: ", "Count" + mDrawerList.getAdapter().getCount());

         }
           }
```

**Update:**

I am not and will not be using the **`configChanges`**, I am handling the orientation change manually. Thanks

Comment: I guess, after you get your onOrientationChange, the `position` will no longer be filled.

Comment: After you change orientation, your Activity is re-created, and all variables inside that Activity, are re-initialized. So `position` is no longer filled.

Comment: Do you have a specific layout file `drawer_layout` for both `layout-land` and `layout`?

Comment: Can you post here complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest...

```
<activity android:name="Your Activity Name"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: Soory I forgot to mention that I am not using `configChanges`, so I am handling it manually. Thanks